# small text not going all the way to the margins

Tags: margins, geometry, vspace

I have been trying to put smal text to the very top left of the page by using the geometry package and setting the margins to 0, but it doesn't go all the way - there is a slight vspace to the right and the top of the word.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not set the margin to 0. You should use some other packages instead.

Comment: @JouleV Is there one you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a small line of text in the corner of the paper, you have many option (but **not** by using `[margin=0pt]{geometry}`!) – in this answer I will show the Ti*k*Z approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,inner sep=0pt,font=\fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont] {This is for test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If the very thin space on the top and on the left should not be there, you can set `inner sep` to a negative number

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,inner sep=-0.5pt,font=\fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont] {This is for test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

or set `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` separately

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,inner xsep=-0.5pt, inner ysep=-0.4pt,font=\fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont] {This is for test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

However, for readability, I suggest you should not remove that very thin space.